# how to capitalize the input in TextInput in react native? i cant capitalize the sentence, words or characters by autoCapitalize property of TextField

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';   
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {text: ''};
  }
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{padding: 10}}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
        autoCapitalize="characters"
```

> here autoCapitalize doesnt works on my android.

```
        autoFocus="true"
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text:text})}
      /> 
      <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
        {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
      </Text>
    </View>
 );
}
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testapp', () => PizzaTranslator);
```

> I have samsung galaxy S6 with marshmallow api level 23 and i am currently testing on that. This autocapitalize works on other android but not on mine . I just noticed this. Does mobile effects the property?

Comment: just change onChangeText to onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text: text.toUpperCase() })}

Comment: but why autoCapitalize property is not working? this should work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that this happens only on my samsung default keyboard. I downloaded another keyboards and autoCapitalize was working on other keyboards.